# How do I automatically populate a new table in MS-Access with info from an existing table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am very new to MS Access and I am struggling with some things that seem like they should be the most basic.  I have imported a table of data from Excel and have defined the data types for the fields.  I have no problem there, but now I want to make a new table that has as a primary key one of the fields from the imported table.  It looks like I can manually create this table, set the relationship, and then go back and type in each record associated with the new primary key, but this seems completely ridiculous.  Surely there must be a way to automatically create one record for each unique instance in the matching field from the original table.  Yet, I've scrolled through hundreds of pages of Access tutorials and Googled the question and found no satisfactory guidance.

Do I completely misunderstand what Access is all about?  How do I create a new table with entries from a field on an existing table?  What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify, the table you are importing has a Primary Key, and you want to have it so the secondary table has a matching record with that Primary key.   So basically if you import a table with 10 records, you want 10 blanks records created on that second table with only primary key filled out?  Is this accurate?

Comment: It'd be easiest if you created an example of what you want the tables to look like, and then the community could probably give you some advice on how to create that.

Comment: @Newd, Sort of.  So, I have a table that has a lot of reports about ships (what I imported).  Now I want to create a database of that information.  It seems to me like I should be able to do things like create a table of ship names.  For the new table where ship name is the primary key, each unique ship name that shows up on the imported table (where the report number is the primary key) should be entered as a record on the newly created table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of Access you are using, the suggestions listed below apply to 2010, but should be similar is other versions.

You can create new tables from existing tables using either a 'Make Table' option after selecting 'Create' -> 'Query Design', or you can manually create your table first, then use an 'Append' query.

Without knowing the design of your table it's hard to get more descriptive. 
Are you populating your new table's primary key ahead of time, or relying on Auto Number to do it (preferred method)?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, I have a primary key for the imported information.  What I want to be able to do is make a new table with a different primary key that is taken from one of the fields of the existing data.  I would have thought this would be a fundamental function of database software.  It is surprising to me that 1) this isn't one of the first things you learn in tutorials and 2) that people have a hard time trying to understand what I'm asking for.  Based on this, I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what database software does.

Comment: So the main question is: "What is the data type of the Primary Key that you want to use?"  For the best results, it should be an integer. This isn't one of the first things learned because it's not done often. Best Practice is to allow Access to assign its own Primary Key via an Auto Number field. You may use other fields for reference or foreign keys. Using fields such as ship names as a primary key is often discouraged as it is possible for two ships to have the name.